# ReactJs - Reactstrap | Jambotron not setting gray background

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to set gray background using Jambotron in reactstrap.

I have installed and referred it at required places -
`index.js` -

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

Jumbotron I have implemented in SignIn.js -

```
import React from 'react'
import Amazon_logo from '../../assets/Amazon_logo.png'
import { Jumbotron, Container  } from 'reactstrap';
function SignIn() {
    return (
        <>
        <div>
            <img src={Amazon_logo} style={{width:"10%",margin:"1% 2% 2%"}} ></img>
        </div>
        <div style={{fontSize:'200%',fontWeight:'bold',margin:'1% 2% 2%'}} >
            SignIn To Shopbot/East Dane using your Amazon account
        </div>
        <Jumbotron >
           <Container >
           <span>Login</span> 
           <span> <input type="text" ></input> </span>
           </Container>
        </Jumbotron>
        </>
    )
}

export default SignIn
```

But when I see , gray portion is not getting implemented as shown in reactstrap document -

https://reactstrap.github.io/components/jumbotron/

[image]

Here is what I can see on screen -

[image]

**EDIT 1 :**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "reactstrap": "^8.9.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably happens because you're using `Bootstrap 5` with `Reactstrap`. According to the `Reactstrap` documentation, the components are designed for `Bootstrap 4`, See:
[About the Project - Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRVRX.png). There's also an issue in their repository talking about the new `Bootstrap 5` upgrade plan. [See](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/1748).

I would recommend you to use the same version that the documentation is consuming to avoid breaking changes. Like this (here we're using the latest 4.x version, which is 4.6):

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "4.6.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "reactstrap": "8.9.0"
  }
```

Another point to consider is that the `Jumbotron` component has been dropped in `Bootstrap 5` as it can be replicated with utilities, [See](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#jumbotron). There's also an example from the official `Bootstrap` documentation right here about how to create the same `Jumbotron` component with custom utilities. [See](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/jumbotron/). You can do the same.

Here is an example with both, `Bootstrap 4` and `Bootstrap 5`:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  Jumbotron,
  Button,
  Container,
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  Label,
  Input,
} from "reactstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <h1 className="display-3">In Bootstrap 4!</h1>
      <Jumbotron>
        <Form>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="exampleEmail">Email</Label>
            <Input
              type="email"
              name="email"
              id="exampleEmail"
              placeholder="with a placeholder"
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <Button color="primary">Learn More</Button>
        </Form>
      </Jumbotron>

      <h1 className="display-3">In Bootstrap 5!</h1>
      <div className="p-5 mb-4 bg-light rounded-3">
        <Jumbotron>
          <Form>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="exampleEmail">Email</Label>
              <Input
                type="email"
                name="email"
                id="exampleEmail"
                placeholder="with a placeholder"
              />
            </FormGroup>
            <Button color="primary">Learn More</Button>
          </Form>
        
        </Jumbotron>
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

There's also another solution to re-add the `.jumbotron` class styles from `Bootstrap 4` to your project `stylesheet` like this:

```
.jumbotron {
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  background-color: #e9ecef;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
}
```

Comment: Now I have taken bootstrap 4.0 , but still its not appearing.. Please check EDIT 1 showing dependancies

Comment: Yeah , Killed the port and re-ran. Bootstrap version was the exact issue. Got the gray background. Thanks